# Cant get current date yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.
Trying get `NSString` with current date with format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
_convenienceFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
_convenienceFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-mm-dd";
NSString *string = [_convenienceFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

**Output is** : 2016-37-14

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `Months` are capital M, lowercase m are `minutes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your coding

```
NSDateFormatter *convenienceFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
convenienceFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-mm-dd";
NSString *string = [convenienceFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

It gives me 2016-14-14

```
NSDateFormatter *Formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
Formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSString *stringFor = [Formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

But above code gives me 2016-07-14

> NOTE: Generally mm indicates minutes.MM indicates month

[Date Formatting Table](http://Date%20Formatting%20Table)

[Dates](http://benscheirman.com/2010/06/dealing-with-dates-time-zones-in-objective-c/)

[Date Programming](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/dates)

[Date Formatter](http://nsdateformatter.com/)

Comment: Thank you brother.In your way I do this.

Comment: @user3182143 thank you, best answer

Comment: Thank you Evgenly Kleban

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your date formatter to `MM` instead of `mm` because `mm` is for `minute` change your code like this

```
_convenienceFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
_convenienceFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSString *string = [_convenienceFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: thank you, it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to write MM and not mm.

```
_convenienceFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
_convenienceFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSString *string = [_convenienceFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: thank you, it work

Answer (score 1):

Try this helper method.

```
-(NSString *) getCurrentDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateformater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateformater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *today=[dateformater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return today;
}
```